# SQL Join statement in iReport

Tags: mysql, sql, join, jasper-reports

I am working on a report that is supposed to display a "PART" and it's quantity of items in both our "WO" (workOrder table) and "SO" (salesOrder table). I believe I have the formatting and everything else completed but for what ever reason I can not seem to get my logic correct with my join statements.

My logic is based off of - Selecting a PART_NUMBER displays the quantity of that part in both a WO and SO. It then adds the total of the columns for SO and WO and then produces a Grand total of each of those.

**I am new to SQL and have been working on this report for 4 days and can not     seem to get it to work. I am assuming my JOINS are off or something. Any help that can be given will be appreciated!**

---

```
SELECT
 COALESCE(woitem.qtytarget,0) AS woallocated,
 COALESCE(soitem.qtyfulfilled,0) AS soallocated,
 PART."NUM" AS PART_NUM,
 WO."NUM" AS WO_NUM,
 PART."ID" AS PART_ID,
 WO."ID" AS WO_ID,
 PART."DESCRIPTION" AS PART_DESCRIPTION,
 SO."ID" AS SO_ID,
 SO."NUM" AS SO_NUM,
 WOITEM."ID" AS WOITEM_ID,
 WOITEM."QTYTARGET" AS WOITEM_QTYTARGET,
 SOITEM."ID" AS SOITEM_ID,
 SOITEM."QTYFULFILLED" AS SOITEM_QTYFULFILLED,
 WOITEM."WOID" AS WOITEM_WOID,
 WOITEM."PARTID" AS WOITEM_PARTID,
 COMPANY."ID" AS COMPANY_ID,
 COMPANY."NAME" AS COMPANY_NAME
FROM
 "PART" PART
 INNER JOIN "WO" WO ON PART."ID" = WO."ID"
 INNER JOIN "SO" SO ON PART."ID" = SO."ID"
 INNER JOIN "WOITEM" WOITEM ON PART."ID" = WOITEM."PARTID"
 AND WO."ID" = WOITEM."WOID"
 INNER JOIN "SOITEM" SOITEM ON SO."ID" = SOITEM."SOID",
 "COMPANY" COMPANY
WHERE
 PART."NUM"=$P{partNum}
```

I am new to SQL and am grateful for any help in my logic!

[image: SQL CODE]

[image: Report Query Design]

[image: Report Design View]

Comment: sounds like you need to do a `Union All`  http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/union_all.php if you want to return all of the information you have in your `Select`

Comment: is it syntax error...

Comment: then what exactly is the problem

Comment: one major problem you have is you're joining `SO` and `WO` on `PART."ID" = WO."ID"`.. that seems unlikely.. you would most likely need to Join WOITEM on PartID then join WO on `WOITEM."WOID" = WO."ID"`

Comment: Something is off with your schema.. SO and SOITEM are related to each other but they're not related to any of the other tables you listed.. is there another table you're missing?

Comment: a part would typically be a line item on an order.. `SO` in your case is the Order (Summary) and `SOITEM` seems to be the line items (Details) so something in `SOITEM` would have to link back to `PART` and i'm 100% sure it's not `SOITEM."ID"`  if anything `SOITEM."PRODUCTID"` might link to `PART."ID"`

Comment: @colt updated my answer

Comment: @JamieD77 Thank you for still taking the time to help me!! I get an error that says- "Dynamic SQL ErrorSQL error code = -206Column unknown PART.ID at line 49, column 28"

Comment: @JamieD77 oh i think that error is coming from the second 'FROM' where it says P.PARTID

Comment: @colt that was the problem

Comment: @JamieD77 so what do i put in place of the 'p'? :3

Comment: the P is just an alias.. you can use whatever you want.. the problem was i forgot your primary keys were all ID and not {tablename}ID.. i updated the answer again

Comment: @JamieD77 so apparently i should have been using the field "QTYTOFULFILL" instead of "QTYFULFILLED" :/. The issue im having now is that the entire report prints odd when i just replace the field name from filled to fulfilled. Any idea why? The report is right - it just doesnt return what im wanting :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this..  You're trying to inner join tables that arent really related so you're getting duplicates.. create 2 queries and Union them with UNION ALL

```
SELECT
 COALESCE(woitem.qtytarget,0) AS woallocated,
 0 AS soallocated,
 PART."NUM" AS PART_NUM,
 WO."NUM" AS WO_NUM,
 PART."ID" AS PART_ID,
 WO."ID" AS WO_ID,
 PART."DESCRIPTION" AS PART_DESCRIPTION,
 NULL AS SO_ID,
 NULL AS SO_NUM,
 WOITEM."ID" AS WOITEM_ID,
 WOITEM."QTYTARGET" AS WOITEM_QTYTARGET,
 NULL AS SOITEM_ID,
 0 AS SOITEM_QTYFULFILLED,
 WOITEM."WOID" AS WOITEM_WOID,
 WOITEM."PARTID" AS WOITEM_PARTID,
 COMPANY."ID" AS COMPANY_ID,
 COMPANY."NAME" AS COMPANY_NAME
FROM
 "PART" PART
 INNER JOIN "WOITEM" WOITEM ON PART."ID" = WOITEM."PARTID"
 INNER JOIN "WO" WO ON WOITEM."WOID" = WO."ID",
 "COMPANY" COMPANY
WHERE
 PART."NUM"=$P{partNum}

UNION ALL

SELECT
 0 AS woallocated,
 COALESCE(soitem.qtyfulfilled,0) AS soallocated,
 PART."NUM" AS PART_NUM,
 NULL AS WO_NUM,
 PART."ID" AS PART_ID,
 NULL AS WO_ID,
 PART."DESCRIPTION" AS PART_DESCRIPTION,
 SO."ID" AS SO_ID,
 SO."NUM" AS SO_NUM,
 NULL AS WOITEM_ID,
 0 AS WOITEM_QTYTARGET,
 SOITEM."ID" AS SOITEM_ID,
 SOITEM."QTYFULFILLED" AS SOITEM_QTYFULFILLED,
 NULL AS WOITEM_WOID,
 NULL AS WOITEM_PARTID,
 COMPANY."ID" AS COMPANY_ID,
 COMPANY."NAME" AS COMPANY_NAME
FROM
 "PART" PART
 INNER JOIN "PRODUCT" P ON PART."ID" = P."PARTID"
 INNER JOIN "SOITEM" SOITEM ON P."ID" = SOITEM."PRODUCTID"
 INNER JOIN "SO" SO ON SOITEM."SOID" = SO."ID",
 "COMPANY" COMPANY
WHERE
 PART."NUM"=$P{partNum}
```

Select only the WO items in the first query, then join that to the SO items..  SO fields will be empty for WO items and vise versa

Comment: would help if you listed the fields in your tables.. what fields are in the SOITEM table?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
 COALESCE(woitem.qtytarget,0) AS woallocated,
 COALESCE(soitem.qtyfulfilled,0) AS soallocated,
 PART.`NUM` AS PART_NUM,
 WO.`NUM` AS WO_NUM,
 PART.`ID` AS PART_ID,
 WO.`ID` AS WO_ID,
 PART.`DESCRIPTION` AS PART_DESCRIPTION,
 SO.`ID` AS SO_ID,
 SO.`NUM` AS SO_NUM,
 WOITEM.`ID` AS WOITEM_ID,
 WOITEM.`QTYTARGET` AS WOITEM_QTYTARGET,
 SOITEM.`ID` AS SOITEM_ID,
 SOITEM.`QTYFULFILLED` AS SOITEM_QTYFULFILLED,
 WOITEM.`WOID` AS WOITEM_WOID,
 WOITEM.`PARTID` AS WOITEM_PARTID,
 COMPANY.`ID` AS COMPANY_ID,
 COMPANY.`NAME` AS COMPANY_NAME
FROM
 `PART` PART
 INNER JOIN `WO` WO ON PART.`ID` = WO.`ID`
 INNER JOIN `SO` SO ON PART.`ID` = SO.`ID`
 INNER JOIN `WOITEM` WOITEM ON PART.`ID` = WOITEM.`PARTID`
 AND WO.`ID` = WOITEM.`WOID`
 INNER JOIN `SOITEM` SOITEM ON SO.`ID` = SOITEM.`SOID`,
 `COMPANY` COMPANY
WHERE
 PART.`NUM`=$P{partNum}
```

use ```  instead of `"` , if it is syntax error.

Hope this helps